# Loop for_each with distinct names?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to get each record below applied in terraform:

```
resource "cdn_record" "domain_com_txt" {
  for_each = {
    "rt1.company.com"                 = "foo"
    "rt2.company.com"                 = "bar"
    "rt1.company.com"                 = "123"
  }

  zone_id = domain_zone.domain_record.id
  name    = each.key
  type    = "TXT"
  ttl     = 1800
  proxied = false
  value   = each.value
}
```

In this example, rt1.company.com ultimately becomes '123' and the first value 'foo' is skipped. How can i get both in my output?

Is it even possible with for_each?

Comment: Why do you have duplicate keys in your map? Consider switching key and value around.

Comment: You can use https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for#grouping-results if you are dynamically constructing a map with non-unique keys. However, you are explicitly defining a map constructor with non-unique keys here, so it is not possible. Note that all languages with map/hash/dict/etc. do not allow non-unique keys, so you would need to fix your structure here.

Comment: or use a list of objects wit 2 properties each ala key and value pairs.

Comment: They are not duplicates - I have multiple records using the same name with different values so that cant be avoided.

Comment: There are duplicate keys. A map must have unique keys, it's just how maps work. As I said, you can actually just switch key and value around, at least for the data you show. More solid would be using an actual list. The below answer is, precisely, what I meant in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using count and index to deal with it:

Observation: I didn't run it, as I don't know what resource "cdn_record" is (I couldn't find it in terraform registry - the resource looks similar to "aws_route53_record")

And use the allow_overwrite flag.

```
locals {
  my-variable = [
    {name ="rt1.company.com", record = "foo"},
    {name ="rt2.company.com", record = "bar"},
    {name ="rt1.company.com", record = "123"}
  ]

  new-variable = values(zipmap(local.my-variable.*.name, local.my-variable))
}


resource "aws_route53_record" "domain_com_txt" {
  count   = length(local.new-variable)
  zone_id = domain_zone.domain_record.id
  name    = local.new-variable[count.index].name
  type    = "TXT"
  ttl     = 1800
  records   = [local.new-variable[count.index].record]

  allow_overwrite = true
}
```

Official reference : [aws_route53_record](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_record)

Comment: It doesnt like line - local.my-variable[count.index].value : 

Error: Invalid index
count.index is 0
local.my-variable is object with 8 attributes
The given key does not identify an element in this collection value. An object only supports looking up attributes by name, not by numeric index.

Comment: I edited my answer, I ran the code with aws_route53_record and it works now.

I had to change my-variable to object format

Answer (score 0):

In DNS, a "recordset" is all of the records with the same hostname and type, where as a "record" is the full tuple of (hostname, type, value). Unfortunately, different DNS services have different API structures where some treat an entire recordset as a single API object while others treat each individual record as its own object.

This difference will typically also be reflected in Terraform providers for these services, since it's typical for a provider developer to define a separate resource type for each object type included in the remote API definition.

It seems like the vendor you are using, and thus the provider for its API, treats each *record* as a separate object, and therefore the hostname alone is not a sufficient unique key for a particular record. You would need to instead use the hostname, type and value together as a unique ID. In your case the type is always fixed to be `TXT` so you can omit that part, but you'll still need to construct compound keys with both the hostname and the value:

```
locals {
  txt_records = [
    {
      name  = "rt1.company.com"
      value = "foo"
    },
    {
      name  = "rt2.company.com"
      value = "bar"
    },
    {
      name  = "rt1.company.com"
      value = "123"
    },
  }
}

resource "cdn_record" "domain_com_txt" {
  for_each = {
    for r in local.txt_records : "${r.name} ${r.value}" => r
  }

  zone_id = domain_zone.domain_record.id
  name    = each.value.name
  type    = "TXT"
  ttl     = 1800
  proxied = false
  value   = each.value.value
}
```

This example starts with a list of objects where each object represents a DNS record which is implied by context to have type `TXT`. The `for_each` expression then uses a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for) to project that list of objects into a map of objects where the keys include both the name and the value together, so that they'll all be unique.

This leads to resource instances with addresses like the following:

- `cdn_record.domain_com_txt["rt1.company.com foo"]`
- `cdn_record.domain_com_txt["rt2.company.com bar"]`
- `cdn_record.domain_com_txt["rt1.company.com 123"]`

Because for this DNS service the whole record is the object being represented, and the value is part of the identity of a record, changing the `value` of one of the elements of `local.txt_records` will be understood by Terraform as needing to destroy an existing record and create a new record, rather than to edit a record in place.

---

You might find it helpful to refer to the various Terraform modules in [the `terraformdns` GitHub organization](https://github.com/terraformdns) to see some fuller examples of mapping data structures describing DNS records onto actual resources for various DNS vendors. Those particular modules start with collections of *recordsets* rather than collections of *records*, so the approach won't be quite the same as what I showed here, but it might still be interesting to see how each of the vendors has some different opinions about how to model recordsets or records in their API and that leads to different approaches to describe the transformation in the Terraform language.